# Best way to run a touchscreen app in kiosk mode on Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: server, qt, touchscreen, kiosk

I'm an embedded dev who switched from weak ARM to powerful Intel Atom hardware, dedicated for running a touchscreen Qt app.

I decided to stop bothering with custom Busybox OS images and use a minimal Ubuntu Server + a few packages to simplify and and have a more standardized base. (I would still use custom disk images for my own point releases of my customized OS.) I haven't yet looked at Ubuntu Core, don't really see the benefit with the beefy hardware I got now.

I'd like to know the best way to get the typical "kiosk mode" behavior out of Ubuntu 20.04. I've identified below a list of some common kiosk requirements, and the approach I thought I'd follow:

1. When the system is powered on, I'd like to show a custom splash screen during boot, not the Ubuntu Server boot sequence. Solution: I found some plymouth theme editing guides.
2. At startup, boot straight into my app in fullscreen mode, without login. Don't show any desktop bar even for a fraction of a second. This will likely involve some session configuration, then a systemd startup service.
3. Disable all screensavers and locks. Didn't look into it, but should be trivial.
4. On app crash, auto-restart the app. Solution: restart policy in systemd service definition.
5. Disable all USB ports, to disallow the use of keyboard and mouse. Solution: nousb kernel boot flag.
6. Minimal dependencies to run my app: either use ubuntu-desktop-minimal, or start from xorg and add the minimum needed.

But just because I can piece solutions together doesn't necessarily mean it's the right way. I thought I'd ask here. I figured this is not such a rare use-case, so perhaps there's an established approach I should be following.